# One liner for poping list of lists based on condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I've got the following lists:

`leftoverbricks = [['purple1', 'y8', 'x0', 'y8', 'x1'], ['purple2', 'y6', 'y0', 'x8', 'y0'], ['purple3', 'z2', 'x8', 'z2', 'x0']]`

and

`startingbrick = ['purple3', 'z2', 1, 1]`

I'd like to pop an element from leftoverbricks where `startingbrick[0]` matches first element of list of list from leftoverbricks, so `leftoverbricks[][0]`

I've created a function that works:

```
def removebrick(tempbrick, templist):
    reducedlist = templist
    for tempelement in reducedlist:
        if tempelement[0] == tempbrick[0]:
            reducedlist.pop(reducedlist.index(tempelement))
    return reducedlist
```

and which gives the correct result of:

`reducedleftoverbricks = removebrick(startingbrick, leftoverbricks)`

`reducedleftoverbricks = [['purple1', 'y8', 'x0', 'y8', 'x1'], ['purple2', 'y6', 'y0', 'x8', 'y0']]`

But it's not elegant. I hope such thing can be done with one liner and by mutating original `leftoverbricks` list rather than creating a new list variable `reducedleftoverbricks`. I did a few attempts at one liner list comprehension but so far failed.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd consider using a filter. Note that the filter is going to be lazily evaluated, so you can evaluate the whole filter in the spot where you'd like the reduced list.

```py
for brick in filter(lambda n: n[0] != startingbrick[0], leftoverbricks):
   do_more_work(brick)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would be a good use-case for *filter()*.

e.g.,

```
leftoverbricks = [['purple1', 'y8', 'x0', 'y8', 'x1'], ['purple2', 'y6', 'y0', 'x8', 'y0'], ['purple3', 'z2', 'x8', 'z2', 'x0']]
startingbrick = ['purple3', 'z2', 1, 1]

def removebrick(tempbrick, templist):
    key, *_ = templist
    return list(filter(lambda v: v[0] != key, tempbrick))

print(removebrick(leftoverbricks, startingbrick))
```

**Output:**

```
[['purple1', 'y8', 'x0', 'y8', 'x1'], ['purple2', 'y6', 'y0', 'x8', 'y0']]
```

**Note:**

This does not modify the input list (leftoverbricks). If you want it to be destructive then just assign the return value from this function to the appropriate variable